# ASIHTTPRequest and userInfo

Tags: iphone, set, asihttprequest, userinfo

According to the website for ASIHTTPRequest:

> If your requests are all of the same
>   broad type, but you want to
>   distinguish between them, you can set
>   the userInfo NSDictionary property of
>   each request with your own custom data
>   that you can read in your finished /
>   failed delegate methods.

How do I set userInfo?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
request.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: dataObject, key, nil];
```

Comment: I have a java server and I set UserInfo, can I get that userInfo on server side or this is for client side only?

Answer (score 2):

```
request.userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"init", @"operation", nil];
```

otherwise you will get an error like: mutating method sent to immutable objectt

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer brackets to dot notation:

```
[request setUserInfo:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"init", @"operation", nil]];
```